# How to store third-party API array data into elephantSQL database using React.js front-end and node.js back-end?

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, api, post

Coding newbie here. So I've been trying to build a dictionary app using wordsapi and was trying to find a way to store the dictionary api into my back end. Below is my code on the front end using React.

```
const _addToQuollection = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3333/quollection/add';
    const submitResponse = await fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ word: word, definition: definition }),
    })
        .then((response) => response)
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    console.log("word added to quollection: ", submitResponse)
    
    if (submitResponse.status === 200) {
        console.log("submit response is success")
    }
}
```

In my console, the req body information for word and definition array pops up as so... [console.log picture showing req body for string word and array definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1KP3.png)

But the post request is only inserting into word and not definition... [QUERY: INSERT INTO quollection (word) VALUES ('quote'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXKPo.png)

My backend route using Node.js looks like this...

```
router.post('/add', async(req, res) => {
console.log('backend reqBody: ', req.body);
const { word, definition } = req.body;
const response = await quollectionModel.addToQuollection(word, definition);
if (response.rowCount >= 1) {
    console.log('def added success!')
    res.sendStatus(200)
} else {
    res.sendStatus(500)
}
```

});

And the backend model looks like this...

```
    static async addToQuollection(word, definition) {
    try {
        const response = await db.result(`INSERT INTO quollection (word, definition) VALUES ($1, $2);`, [word, definition]);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error.message)
        return error.message
    }
}
```

This was how I created my schema...

```
CREATE TABLE quollection (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
word text,
definition text[1000000]
);
```

And this is the result in postico...
[postico screenshot with successful word column and null definition column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSAbq.png)

Ahhh I hope this was a decent enough explanation. Any help would be much appreciated T_T Thank you!

Comment: Your question is very detailed and very well structured. The only thing I suggest you is to keep your question professional. StackOverflow is a repository of code-related questions and you should write them like if you are writing on an encyclopedia. So it's better to avoid general thanks or specifying "coding newbie" here. Comments are more suited and also upvotes are appreciated as a "thank you". Commonly, you don't know these practices since this is your first post, however, remember them for future times.